# setMessageBody() emailDialog titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, email, titanium

I am trying to create a list of 'sent emails'. My theory is that when the user sends an email, the data in subject & messagebody is saved as an object and pushed into a tableView list data array. I have been reading up on it and I know I can set the subject and messageBody as Strings to appear each time the user opens the email to send a new one, but what I am having trouble with is saving the contents the user enters into these fields, so once it has been sent, it saves the information for them to view later. I'm not sure if what I am trying to do will work. I have come across a similar question here on these forums and it was concluded that this could not be done, but the question is 3 years old, so maybe there have been some further developments.

So, my question to the gurus out there, is this functionality even possible? to save the data the user enters?

I know I can do it without using emailDalog and just using textFields, but of course it wont 'look' like a proper email.

Backgound: it is for a small iPhone gaming application and the user can email the developer directly with any issues or feedback. so I have set the subject, messageBody and recipient fields with appropriate text to start a new email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm pretty sure there is no API for that. As soon as the user enters the standard mail UI, Titanium is out of control. 
And you cannot access the local database where the mail app stores it's data.